# Unable to start Oracle database

Tags: oracle, recovery, datafile

I have a oracle database, one data file(users table space) of the instance got corrupt and another data file(containing application data) was deleted due to some issue.
The database is in ARCHIVELOG mode but we neither have data file backup of both data files nor the pertaining archive logs. Hence, I guess we cannot go ahead with the recovery of data files. I am unable to open the database as the data files are not available and face.

```
ORA-01589: must use RESETLOGS or NORESETLOGS option for database open
```

I am just able to `STARTUP MOUNT` the database

I wanted to ask if we can somehow we can open the database by taking both the table spaces offline after `STARTUP MOUNT` the database instance. Or if there is any other way I can start the database.